# WPF MainWindow freezes even in Asynchronous state

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, mainwindow

What I'm trying to do is perform a heavy task triggered by a button event on the MainWindow, but still be able to drag the window freely. I've tried both the async/await pattern and creating new threads. However, threads will be nonblocking, MainWindow still freezes. Here's the code:

```
uiTIN.Click += async (o, e) =>
{
    var _ = await Task.Run(() => job());
};
```

That's the button callback and here is the func:

```
    private int job()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        { 
         //Other function calls here omitted
        });
     return 0;
    }
```

**EDIT:**  The workaround was to use BackgroundWorker and I have also decorated dependent UI code snippets in Dispatcher Invoke function

Comment: Everything inside Dispatcher.Invoke is performing on UI thread, try to place only UI related code to Dispatcher.Invoke call.

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke will operate on your UI Thread. You should try a background worker

Comment: **Why** did you use `Dispatcher`?

Comment: You are using an `async void`  _and_ a `Task.Run` and then finally  push all the work back to the main thread...

Comment: Step 1, separate time consuming business logic from the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft's doccumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) on Dispatcher (emphasis mine):

> In WPF, a `DispatcherObject` can only be accessed by the `Dispatcher` it is associated with.  For example, a background thread cannot update the contents of a `Button` that is associated with the `Dispatcher` on the UI thread. **In order for the background thread to access the `Content` property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the `Dispatcher` associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`**. `Invoke` is synchronous and `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous. The operation is added to the queue of the `Dispatcher` at the specified `DispatcherPriority`.

So basically what you're doing is call an asynchronous method, and then forcing it to run on the UI thread, which accomplishes nothing.

In your `//Other function calls here omitted`, I'm asuming that you need to access some part of the UI, if that's not the case, all you have to do is remove the `Dispatcher.Invoke` from your method.

If my assumptions are right, then you must figure out a way of splitting your function, so that the part that isn't UI related run in a Background thread and only what needs to run on the UI Thread actually do.

My suggestion is to use a [`Background Worker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Here's how it'd look:

```
uiTIN.Click += (o, e) =>
{
    job();
};
```

... and then ...

```
private int job()
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Part of other function calls here omitted that don't need to run on the UI thread

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            // Part of other function calls here omitted that must run on the UI thread
        });
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I had a speculation regarding this. Now that you put it this way, it doesn't make much sense to do UI related tasks in background because that's why UI is all about.

Answer (score 0):

The normal practice is that you have to return from buttons onClick event callback as soon as you can in order to avoid blocking the main thread(or some refer to UI thread). If the main thread is blocked the application will look like frozen. This is a fundamental design of any GUI application to synchronize UI flow.

You start an async task in callback but you also wait for the task to finish before returning. You should start a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the onClick event then return.

Answer (score 0):

It has been explained quite well already why your code was blocking the UI thread (queuing your work on the Dispatcher). But I would not recommend the usage of the `BackgroundWorker`, I would rather fix your code with `Task.Run` for several reasons all explained in this article: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html